# Is the Čech complex of a coherent sheaf on a compact separated rigid analytic space admissible?

Tags: rigid-analytic-geometry, berkovich-geometry

$\newcommand{\F}{\mathcal{F}}\newcommand{\O}{\mathcal{O}}$Let $X$ be a compact, separated rigid $k$-analytic space over some complete non-archimedean field $k$. Then $X$ has a finite affinoid covering $X = U_1 \cup \dots \cup U_n$ by affinoid domains and all the higher intersections of the $U_i$ are again affinoid.

Let $\F$ be a sheaf of coherent $\O_X$-modules. By Kiehl's theorem, the restriction of $\F$ to each $U_i$ is associated to some finite $\O_X(U_i)$-module. In particular $\F(U_i)$ is a finite $\O_X(U_i)$-module and hence carries a norm making it into a finite Banach module, which is unique up to equivalence. Similarly for $\F(U_i \cap U_j)$ etc..

Equipping the direct products with the maximum norm, the Čech complex associated to the covering $(U_i)_i$ is a complex of Banach $k$-vector spaces:
$$0 \to \prod_{i = 1}^n\F(U_i) \to \prod_{i,j=1}^n \F(U_i \cap U_j) \to \dots.$$

> Are the boundary maps admissible maps of Banach spaces? (A map is called admissible if there is some constant $C$ such that every element in the image has some preimage of norm $\le$ $C$ times the norm of that element.)

The question of admissibility is essentially equivalent to the question, whether the Čech cohomology (and hence the sheaf cohomology) carries a sensible Banach norm.

If $X$ is affinoid, then by Tate's acyclicity theorem, the (augmented) Čech complex is exact and hence admissible by Banach's open mapping theorem. But what about this more general situation?

Comment: I've been told that it's a well-known hard problem whether the topology on the cohomology induced by the Cech complex is Hausdorff or not.

Comment: @DavidLoeffler That is good to know. Is it known that the topology on the cohomology groups is independent of the chosen covering? (If it were Hausdorff for all coverings, then this would also follow from Banach's theorem.)

Comment: Good question. It is claimed in Le Stum's "Rigid Cohomology" (page 173, sect 5.4) that Banach's theorem implies the topology is independent of the choice of covering; but he doesn't give a proof, and I don't see how it should go.